# What are some good Figures of Merit for different lithography techniques?

Tags: lithography

Could someone explain what figures of merit can be applied to lithography techniques such as DPN and LON?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! Sadly, I felt I had to down vote your question, because it doesn't even show an attempt at any own research, which would have been relatively easy, since you already know two types that you can, with the help of Google and Wikipedia, for example, compare yourself, and then ask a more specific question about something that you can't understand. This feels like you're trying to get us to do your learning or your homework, both of which things that help nobody else in the community and in the long run hurt our profession.

Answer (score 1):

Selective  Scanning Beam Lithograhy (SBL) area rate must be the most critical limiting FoM.

SBL is very slow (requiring up to 24 hours per cm2 for 20 nm scale features)
but its high resolution and pattern fidelity make it a critical technology for the fabrication of masks for photolithography. SBL has also been used in niche research applications in bioelectronics.